# Converting an MVC4 Web API Application to Phonegap Android Application

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC4 Web API application where i have my Api Controller and Code-First EF5 database and some JavaScript functions for the functionality of my app including my Ajax Calls for my Web Api Service.I did the project on MVC because i was having trouble installing Cordova in VS2012, so i have decided to use Eclipse/Android Phonegap platform.Is there a way where i can call my web api service and be able to retrieve my database data designed EF5(MVC4) in my Android Phonegap application without having to start from the beginning the same thing again.I know phonegap is basically Html(JavaScript and Css) but i am having trouble calling my service using the same HTML markup that i used MVC4.I am a beginner please let me know if what i am doing is possible and if not please do show me the light of how i can go about this. T**his is my Html code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-2.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="barcodescanner.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://api.afrigis.co.za/loadjsapi/?key=...&version=2.6">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

//initialize watchID Variable

var watchID = null;
// device APIs are available

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Throw an error if no update is received every 30 seconds
    var options = { timeout: 30000 };
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

    // onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                        '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
}

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

}
    //declare a global map object
    var agmap = null;

    // declare zoom control of map
    var zoomCtrl = null;
    function initAGMap() {

        agmap = new AGMap(document.getElementById("MapPanel"));
         //TODO: must retrieve coords by device location not hard corded.

        agmap.centreAndScale(new AGCoord(-25.7482681540537, 28.225935184269), 5); // zoom level 5 heres
        // making zoom controls for map
        var ctrlPos = new AGControlPosition(new AGPoint(10, 10), AGAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
        zoomCtrl = new AGZoomControl(1);
        agmap.addControl(zoomCtrl, ctrlPos);
    }

    function removeZoomCtrl()
    {
        zoomCtrl.remove();
    }

    //function search() {
    //    var lat = $('#latitude').val();
    //    var long = $('#longitude').val();

    //    $.ajax({
    //        url: "api/Attractions/?longitude=" + long + "&latitude=" + lat,
    //        type: "GET",
    //        success: function (data) {
    //            if (data == null) {
    //                $('#attractionName').html("No attractions to search");
    //            }
    //            else {
    //                $('#attractionName').html("You should visit " + data.Name);
    //                displayMap(data.Location.Geography.WellKnownText, data.Name);
    //            }

    //        }

    //    });

    //}

    //function GetCoordinate() {
        //todo: get details from cordova, currently mocking up results
       //return { latitude: -25.5, longitude: 28.5 };
    }
    function ShowCoordinate(coords) {
        agmap.centreAndScale(new AGCoord(coords.latitude, coords.longitude), 5); // zoom level 5 here
        var coord = new AGCoord(coords.latitude, coords.longitude);
        var oMarker = new AGMarker(coord);
        agmap.addOverlay(oMarker);
        oMarker.show();

        //todo: create a list of places found and display with marker on AfriGIS Map.
    }

    function ScanProduct()
    {
        //todo retrieve id from cordova as mockup
        //This is mockup barcode 
        //return "1234";
        //sample code using cordova barcodescanner plugin
                  var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");
                  scanner.scan(
                  function (result) {
                  alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                  "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                  "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                  "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
            },

       //Callback function if barcodedont exist

            function (error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            });
    }
    //Function to display Success or error in encoding.

     function encode(type, data) {
        window.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(type, data, function(result) {
               alert("encode success: " + result);
            }, function(error) {
                 alert("encoding failed: " + error);
            });}



    function GetProductDetails(barcodeId,coords) 
    {
        //Ajax Call to my web Api service 
        $.getJSON("api/products/?barcodeId=" + barcodeId + "&latitude=" + coords.latitude + "&longitude=" + coords.longitude)
          .done(function (data) {
              $('#result').append(data.message)
              console.log(data)
              var list = $("#result").append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
              $.each(data.results, function (i, item)
              {
                   if (data.results == null) {

                      $('#result').append(data.message)
                  }

                  else {


                      list.append('<li>ShopName :' + item.retailerName + '</li>');
                      list.append('<li>Name : ' + item.productName + '</li>');
                      list.append('<li>Rand :' + item.price + '</li>');
                      list.append('<li>Distance in Km :' + item.Distance + '</li>');

                      //Another Solution 

                      //var ul = $("<ul></ul>")
                      //ul.append("<li> Rand" + data.results.productName + "</li>");
                      //ul.append("<li> Rand" + data.results.Retailer.Name + "</li>");
                      //ul.append("<li> Rand" + data.results.price + "</li>");
                      //ul.append("<li> Rand" + data.results.Distance + "</li>");
                      //$("#result").append(ul);
                  }

              });

              $("#result").append(ul);

          });
        }

    function ShowProductDetails()
    {
        //todo: display product details  
        //return productdetails.barcodeId + productdetails.retailerName + ': R' + productdetails.Price + productdetails.Distance;
    }
        //loading javascript api
        $(function () {
            initAGMap();

            var coord = GetCoordinate();
            ShowCoordinate(coord);
            var barcodeId = ScanProduct();
            var productdetails = GetProductDetails(barcodeId, coord);
            ShowProductDetails(productdetails);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having? Can you post some code?

Comment: @Anthony i edited and pasted my html code where i have my Ajax that calls my web api service.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track. The obvious error right now is that it's using a relative URL (`api/products/?barcodeId=`) to call the Web API. Because the HTML is no longer hosted on the same server as the Web API (even though you might be running them both on your local machine still), this won't work anymore. You need to call the service with an absolute URL (for example, `http://localhost:8888/api/products/?barcodeId=`).

Where is your Web API hosted right now and how are you running the Cordova code? If the Web API is up and running on your local machine and your Cordova app is running on an emulator on the same machine, you should be able to call the service by supplying its full localhost path.

If it still doesn't work, you'll need to somehow debug the code and see what the errors are.

Comment: Thank you i did try that out and it worked like a charm after weeks of struggling though but now my i cannot access  the site on an android device(Motorola razor or Samsung S4) i can run the site on any machine from Firefox,chrome and even IE but i only get a map displayed when hitting the site on an android browser and i cannot see the Products Details(my results) i used getJson in my call so i am thinking that the problem might be the way i call the ajax call so the mobile browsers does not like the way i call the api pleas help to solve this and how can i get this to work on mobile

Comment: $.getJSON
("api/products/?barcodeId=
" + barcodeId + "&latitude=" + coords.latitude + 
"&longitude=" + coords.longitude)
.done(function (data) 
 {
$('#result').append(data.message)
 console.log(data)